# Convert doc,pdf into html or printable format in asp.net/C#

Tags: asp.net, html, pdf, document, converters

I am using c# and asp.net 3.5 for a client project.
In my project my client uploads Microsoft word document or PDF on the site and I have to show this document in html format for printing.
This document are going to have many images or charts.
And we are not going to use Microsoft Interop Library. 
I have tried aspose and the result was not very good.
I don't known if iTextSharp can convert PDF with images to html document.
Can someone guide me on how to do this work?

Thanks For your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply showing the documents via [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Coverting PDF to HTML is complex.There are many libraries that convert PDF to image. Can you show the converted image in your web page for printing??

You can try O2 solutions/aspose

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago I had developed a windows service which used the Microsoft Interop Library to open documents published on a folder and convert them in **HTML** and **PDF**.
The only problem was I had to install **MS Office** on the server cause I needed to support documents **97/2000**.
If you just need to support new formats you can try to have a look at the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).